# how to ssh into a machine, run a command and return before the command has completed

Tags: ssh

is it possible to ssh into a machine, run a command and return before the command has completed.

I've tried doing it in the snippet of bash script below

```
for ip in $ipaddrs
do
    ssh pi@192.168.1.$ip 'sudo apt-get update' > /dev/null &
done
```

thanks

update:
an issue is that I'm updating multiple machines and as the output stream is sent to null, I won't know if its worked (which I'm unsure it will) until its finished. Is it possible to use tmux in the script instead?

so ssh in, start tmux, start the update in the tmux shell, detach from the tmux shell and close the ssh session.

then if needs be, I can always ssh into a few machines and reattach the tmux shell to check all is well.

-how do you start tmux in a script?
-how do you detach from tmux in a script?

Comment: `ssh pi@host 'nohup sudo apt-get update </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1'`

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the whole command with single quotes:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.$ip 'sudo apt-get update > /dev/null &'
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting tmux for this is overkill. It can be done; but you're better off using standard shell constructs.

You can use the `-n` option to ssh so that it doesn't prompt for, or ask for passwords. We redirect the output to a set of known files, one per IP. You should use an appropriate directory for these files so that they don't interfere with parallel executions of the scripts (exercise for reader). We run the ssh commands in parallel, and interpret the results once all the ssh sessions have concluded.

```
# remove log files on termination
trap 'rm -f /tmp/sshlog-*.log' EXIT HUP

# loop
for ip in $ipaddrs
do
    # use -n to redirect input appropriately, force public key to prevent password prompt.
    ssh -o "preferredauthentications publickey" -n pi@192.168.1.$ip 'sudo apt-get update; echo "Exit Status: $?"' > /tmp/sshlog-${ip}.log 2>&1 &
done

# Wait for all the tasks to complete
wait

# check the exit statuses
for ip in $ipaddrs
do
    exitcode=$(tail -1 /tmp/sshlog-${ip}.log | sed -n 's/Exit Status: //p')
    # something went wrong/no exit status output
    if [[ $exitcode != 0 ]]; then
        echo "Error: Failed on $ip: " 1>&2
        cat /tmp/$sshlog-${ip}.log 1>&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: sorry, could you explain whats going on a little more, with this line for example
ssh -n pi@192.168.1.$ip 'sudo apt-get update; echo "Exit Status: $?"' > /tmp/sshlog-${ip}.log 2>&1 &

and passwords aren't a problem as I've already set-up the ssh keys

Comment: The `-n` option to ssh prevents the ssh processes from being stopped due to remote processes prompting for input. the ssh command is broken into two commands. Firstly run the apt-get update, then print out the exit code from that invocation `$?`. All the output from the command is redirected to a file called `/tmp/sshlog-${ip}.log` (stdout & stderr)

Comment: I added in a `-o "preferredauthentications publickey"` to force the use of a public key *only* for the ssh connection

Comment: The redirection: `> /tmp/sshlog-${ip}.log` causes stdout to be redirected to the file, the addition of `2>&1` causes stderr to be redirected to that file as well, i.e. it traps all the output from the ssh command in a single file.